# Grunt + Karma fails with disconnected in Chrome

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a JavaScript project with Grunt and Karma. When running tests everything works correctly except in Chrome. I get the following DISCONNECTED message:
(Note that the test that it stops to is different every time)

```
Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 8): Executed 898 of 3031 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.448 secs)
Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 8): Executed 898 of 3031 DISCONNECTED (2.419 secs / 0.448 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:chrome" failed. Use --force to continue.

Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 8): Executed 924 of 3031 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.427 secs)
Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 8): Executed 924 of 3031 DISCONNECTED (2.424 secs / 0.427 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:chrome" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I have tried setting browserNoActivityTimeout value to 30000, 60000, 90000, 12000000 with no effect.

My tests are written in Jasmine. Using karma-jasmine to run the tests. I am also using jasmine-jquery to test the DOM.

Comment: If I remember well, karma has different drivers for each browsers. So I would [create an issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues) if I were you...

Comment: I have the same problem, altough I'm testing the main angular repo. Strangely enough for me it only happens when I use iit.